# Two Accounts Using Same OpenID on Careers 2.0 Causing Issues

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Somehow I have gotten two accounts set up in the Careers 2.0 system with the same OpenID (Google).  Now whenever I log in from a "fresh computer" (no cookies or anything) I can only reach one of the accounts and not the other. The biggest problem with this is that the one I cannot reach is the one which actually has a publicly listed profile and is getting offers.

How I believe this happened is that I registered for Careers 1.0 and only confirmed *after* 2.0 was set up....  This account ended up allowing me to configure some profile settings but did not allow for public listing.

Recently I got an invite from the system to add a new account, so I jumped on the opportunity to have a properly listed profile. I expected it to just elevate my previous profile, but when I went to register it with the same email it wouldn't let me.  So I associated another email with it and ended up with the problem as stated above.

I can still access the other account from the computer I registered with originally (haven't munged that cookie yet) and I of course get emails related to that account.

**How might I go about merging accounts such that this issue gets resolved?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just merged your accounts.  Can you double check that everything looks good?

Comment: Everything appears to be working fine. Thank you!  I would comment that some of the merge things clobbered the more correct information, but I can fix that pretty easily.  

Also, the _very_ fast response time was much appreciated.